# How to access webhook payload in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I wonder how I can access the webhook payload in the fulfillment tab/dialogue, as I am trying to write it in text to the user.

So, for example a session parameter can be accessed through "$session.params.breakfast", but I am wondering what to write to access a webhook payload. In the webhook payload pictured, I would be interested in accessing the value to the key "hello".

[image: Picture of webhook]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is not possible to access payload information from the dialogue. Payloads are supposed to be information stored for future/other webhooks.

I have found that sending information as parameters is the correct alternative, if the goal is to access the information from the dialogue.